# Single Sign-On on Bluemix: how to retrive user profile after binding SSO service to Liberty

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I create an app, and bind it to Liberty. It works fine. But how could I get the user profile after user login?
I saw there is a "Return-to url" in integration tab:
https://ssoConfigboard.mybluemix.net:443/oidcclient/redirect/rwuYaLiy78

But after I visit this url, I got 500 server error:
Error 500: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500

Anybody can help?

Comment: Can you post more of your code or the errors you are getting, it is hard to help you without a little more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same issue using Liberty with the BlueMix SSO service and found this link to be extremely helpful: https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/blogs/sweeden/entry/getting_started_with_ibm_single_sign_on_for_bluemix?lang=en_us

The key point here is that the user info is embedded in the Hashtable of the private credentials. This is not obvious at all. If you download the source code included with this blog you'll find a Java class called: UserHelper.java. This class will extract things like the user name and e-mail address from the WSSubject.

I ended up providing a REST interface in my web app that will allow users that are authenticated using oAuth to access their own user information.

I think one of the reasons this is all so cryptic is that there is a hole in the Java oAuth API standards in this area so this WSSubject class was a workaround to provide a way to access this information.